# Transform EPSG:25830 to EPSG:900913

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, epsg

I have a shapefile file of the "cadastre" of Spain, I use the following command in Linux to get the SQL file to next insert in database with PostGIS (`shp2pgsql -s 900913 PARCELA.SHP> PARCELA.sql`), but after the insert, the polygons appear in Africa and not in Spain, I note that the projection is ETRS89 / UTM zone 30N, but I work with projection EPSG:900913.

How can I transform the shapefile projection to EPSG:900913??

Comment: There is nothing such as 900913. You should be looking at EPSG:3857

Comment: I have also tested with 3857 and I have not gotten it either, but I do use the geom field as geometry (MultiPolygon, 900913)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that your input data is EPSG:25830.

What you should do is to first load that data in it's native CRS. This can be done by a command where you specify the native CRS, like this:

```
shp2pgsql -s 25830 PARCELA.SHP> PARCELA.sql
```

Run this Script to get the Data in your Database.

Once your Data is in the PostGIS database, then you can use the Spatial Functionality to Transform the coordinates into your required CRS.

You want to transform it to WebMercator, whose EPSG Code is 3857.

You could do this by a command like:

```
Select ST_Transform(geom, 3857) from table;
```

If you so wish, save these transformed Geometry to a different table.

Answer (score 2):

Or in one step, following docummentation:

```
root@mapa:/var/log# shp2pgsql 
RELEASE: 2.2.1 (r14555) 
USAGE: shp2pgsql [<options>] <shapefile> [[<schema>.]<table>] OPTIONS:
   -s [<from>:]<srid> Set the SRID field. Defaults to 0.
      Optionally reprojects from given SRID (cannot be used with -D). ...
```

So this should also work

```
shp2pgsql -s 25830:900913 PARCELA.SHP> PARCELA.sql
```